# PHP add String to multidimensional Array, comma seperated

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to add a string to a 3*x Array. I have a string as an input with 150*3 values.

```
<?php
$myString = "5.1,3.5,Red,4.9,3,Blue,4.7,3.2,Red,4.6,3.1,Red,5,3.6,Red," //and so on   

?>
```

the result should look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5.1
            [1] => 3.5
            [2] => Red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.9
            [1] => 3
            [2] => Blue
        )
//and so on

)
```

Comment: what have you tried, then? What went wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty new to PHP. I think I should use two for-loops and I need a method that gets the separation.. but how can I tell the program to take substrings until he hits a comma? And should I work with pointers or should I just erase the substring that I just used?

Comment: You should attempt posting some code, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode()` on the string, and then use `array_chunk()` to chunk the array we have from explode function, keep in mind to check for the chunk size

working snippet: https://3v4l.org/qD1t0

```
<?php
$myString = "5.1,3.5,Red,4.9,3,Blue,4.7,3.2,Red,4.6,3.1,Red,5,3.6,Red"; //and so on 
$arr = explode(",", $myString);
$chunks = array_chunk($Arr, 3);

print_r($chunks);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to convert the comma separated string into an array. Then you can use the [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function.

```
$myString = "5.1,3.5,Red,4.9,3,Blue,4.7,3.2,Red,4.6,3.1,Red,5,3.6,Red";

$explodedStringToArray = explode(',', $myString);
$chunked_array = array_chunk($explodedStringToArray, 3);
print_r($chunked_array);
```

This will produce:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5.1
            [1] => 3.5
            [2] => Red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.9
            [1] => 3
            [2] => Blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.7
            [1] => 3.2
            [2] => Red
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4.6
            [1] => 3.1
            [2] => Red
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 3.6
            [2] => Red
        )

)
```